# Replace characters beginning by \ in a string

Tags: r

I have a random series of characters (random in type and number) beginning by "\" and ending with a space.
I want to replace that by " ".

Here are some possible examples:

```
"car\u09R two" -> "car two"

"bike\x9Uü3 three" -> "bike three"
```

The idea is to make a regex combination for gsub. Something like:

```
gsub("\.*?[:blank:]"," ",string).
```

However, I have issues with the regex code. It is an unrecognized escape.

I know that I would have to write "\" to get "\" in the string. But I also need to use ., *, and ? because I cannot know what the characters will be. And it can be a weird character like û or ü.

What would be the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seems to work for the example provided.

```
 v1 <- c("car\u09R two", "bike\x9Uü3 three")
 gsub("[\t][[:alnum:]]+", "", v1)
 #[1] "car two"    "bike three"
```